# How to convert ms-Excel file to Pdf in java?

Tags: java, excel, pdf

Because I have used `JXL api` for excel  but now I want to convert it to Pdf file so please tell me how to change my code to convert `excel` to `pdf`?

Comment: I dont have much idea about JXL api, but i think [this](http://thinktibits.blogspot.it/2012/12/POI-iText-Convert-XLS-to-PDF-Java-Program.html) might help you

Comment: jxl is a API only used for excel file like itext  for PDFs but here i want to change excel, created by jxl API to dynamically change in pdf..please tell me anyone knows

Answer (score 4):

You could use iText to create a pdf file in java and use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to access the data in the MS-EXCEL file. If you combine both, you could convert your excel file.

A raw example is given [here](http://thinktibits.blogspot.it/2012/12/POI-iText-Convert-XLS-to-PDF-Java-Program.html)

Also, there is this new API:
You can try [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/java/excel-component.aspx) for Java which allows you to convert Excel file to PDF in Java applications. It doesn't require MS Office/OpenOffice etc to be installed on your development or deployment machine. It also works on both Windows and Linux platforms. The code is very simple as shown below:

```
    //Instantiate a new workbook with excel file path
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("F:\\FileTemp\\Book1.xls");

//Save the document in Pdf format
workbook.save("F:\\FileTemp\\MyPdfFile.pdf", FileFormatType.PDF);
```

Comment: `You can try Aspose.Cells` - if you have a couple of hundred $ in your pocket, of course.

Comment: but i want open source  APi which convert excel to pdf at runtime because i have already create in excel file ..please suggest me

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov a couple thousand dollars, that is.